# How to write with innerHTML on input type text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to write something in:

`<input type="text" id="total">`

With

`document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 'hi';`

But it is not writing anything in text box.
Even I also tried it with `className` but still not working.

Is there any solution?

```
<html>
  <body>  
    <h2>My First JavaScript</h2>  
    <input type="text" id="total" >
    <script>
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 'hi';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Input fields have .value not .innerHTML. Also you do not have an ID on your field

Comment: @mplungjan i write by mistake on post class but with id still not working

Comment: You cannot use innerHTML on an input field. Use .value. Please check MDN for syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't set `id` to the `input` and there is no `innerHTML` property of type `input`. Use `value` instead.

```js
document.getElementById('total').value = 'hi';
```

```html
<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>  
<input type="text" id="total" >
```

Comment: @Mamum sorry class i write by mistake on post but with ID still not working

Comment: Please flag as typo-type question. All info is already in comments

Comment: @AbhishekSharma yes it is. You must have other errors. Please press F12 and look in the console

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null i got this error

Comment: Thanx bro now its working.. your ans will be acceptable