# why doesn't my javascript function display my message?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

So i connected a javascript file to my html file. When a button is clicked, it's supposed to display a message but for some reason it doesn't display anything. What am i doing wrong?
(p.s. i know very little about js)

```js
function calc() {
  greeting = "hello"
  var usname = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = greeting;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p> BMI Calculator</p>
</header>
<div class="grid">
  <div class=input>
    <form>
      <p> Fill in the form below</p>
      Name: <br>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br> Weight: <br>
      <input type="number" name="weight"><br> Height: <br>
      <input type="number" name="height"><br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other<br>
      <br><input type="button" onclick="calc()" name="calculate" value="calculate">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <p> Your Results</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the rest of your html code, along with where your script tag is located.

Comment: Input fields don't have innerHTML. You probably meant `.value`.

Comment: Edit your question; don't put code in comments (a command or line is fine, use backticks `\`` to display it as code) your code doesn't produce an error because JS allows adding properties to everything

Comment: Duplicate of [How to write with innerHTML on input type text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48607125/how-to-write-with-innerhtml-on-input-type-text)

Comment: As @GuyIncognito said you have to use `.value` property.

Comment: @Guy Incognito thank you! What is the difference between the two though?

Comment: `innerHTML` is the HTML inside an element. `value` is the value of a form field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```js
var usname = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = greeting;
```

Firstly, you're using an `=` sign twice – I would not do this. There are two options you could use instead:

```js
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = greeting;
```

```js
var usname = document.getElementById("name");
usname.innerHTML = greeting;
```

I've chosen the first option.

The other thing is that, for `input` elements, you need to use `value` and not `innerHTML`. A `div`, `span` or similar element would have `innerHTML` and `innerText` properties, but an input does not.

See the snippet below for a full, working solution:

```js
function calc() {
  greeting = "hello"
  document.getElementById("name").value = greeting;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p> BMI Calculator</p>
</header>
<div class="grid">
  <div class=input>
    <form>
      <p> Fill in the form below</p>
      Name: <br>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br> Weight: <br>
      <input type="number" name="weight"><br> Height: <br>
      <input type="number" name="height"><br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other<br>
      <br><input type="button" onclick="calc()" name="calculate" value="calculate">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <p> Your Results</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the value because you write in a input, or at least make a p

```
  <p name="name" id="name"><br> Weight: <br> </p>
```

(an input has no innerHTML text, but a value)

Or you change JS:

```
document.getElementById("name").value = greeting;
```

Answer (score 0):

you're using a wrong property.
if you had a div like `<div id="name"></div>` then the `document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "abc";` would turn it into `<div id="name">abc</div>`. In your case you want to set the value of the input field, rather than populate more child components.

you can do that with `document.getElementById("name").value = greeting`

Answer (score 0):

use the following modified function :

```
function calc() {
greeting = "hello"
var usname = document.getElementById("name").value = greeting;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are targeting an input element. Input elements don't have the property innerHTML, they have a value, which represents the text.
See snippet

```js
function calc() {
  greeting = "hello"
  var usname = document.getElementById("name");
  var usrname_value = usname.value;
  var message = greeting + usrname_value;
  //Uncomment to save value
  //usname.value = message;

  //change result
  document.querySelector(".result p").innerHTML = message;
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <p> BMI Calculator</p>
</header>
<div class="grid">
  <div class=input>
    <form>
      <p> Fill in the form below</p>
      Name: <br>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br> Weight: <br>
      <input type="number" name="weight"><br> Height: <br>
      <input type="number" name="height"><br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other<br>
      <br><input type="button" onclick="calc()" name="calculate" value="calculate">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <p> Your Results</p>
  </div>
</div>
```